# How to reuse an existing neural network to train a new one using TensorFlow?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I want to train a new neural network using TensorFlow by reusing the lower layers of an existing neural network (which is already trained). I want to drop the top layers of the existing network and replace them with new layers, and I also want to lock the lowest layers to prevent backpropagation from modifying them. Here's a little ascii art to summarize this:

```
*Original model*           *New model*

Output Layer                Output Layer (new)
     |                          |
Hidden Layer 3             Hidden Layer 3 (copied)
     |             ==>          |
Hidden Layer 2             Hidden Layer 2 (copied+locked)
     |                          |
Hidden Layer 1             Hidden Layer 1 (copied+locked)
     |                          |
   Inputs                     Inputs
```

What's a good way to do this?

**Edit**

My original network was created like this:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 500), name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None), name="y")

hidden1 = fully_connected(X, 300, scope="hidden1")
hidden2 = fully_connected(hidden1, 100, scope="hidden2")
hidden3 = fully_connected(hidden2, 50, scope="hidden3")
output = fully_connected(hidden3, 5, activation_fn=None, scope="output)

xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, y)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# ... Train then save the network using the saver
```

What's the code that would load this network, lock the 2 lower hidden layers, and replace the output layer? If possible, it would be great to be able to cache the output of the top locked layer (hidden2) for each input, to speed up training.

**Extra details**

I looked at [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f09c19255acc72279f64b58af38b78bd31cb22aa/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) and the corresponding [How-To](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html) (a very interesting read). The code basically loads the original model, then it computes the output of the bottleneck layer (ie. the last hidden layer before the output layer) for each input. Then it creates a brand new model and trains it using the bottleneck outputs as inputs. This basically answers my question for the copied+locked layers: I just need to run the original model on the whole training set and store the output of the top-most locked layer. But I don't know how to handle the copied but unlocked (ie. trainable) layers (eg. Hidden Layer 3 in my diagram).

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you find the solution? I am dealing the same problem as you.

Answer (score 3):

TensorFlow gives you fine grain control of the set of parameters (`Variable`s) you update in every training step. For instance, in your model, suppose the layers are all fully connected layers. Then you would have a *weights* parameter and *biases* parameter for each layer. Let's say you have the corresponding `Variable` objects in `W1`, `b1`, `W2`, `b2`, `W3`, `b3`, `Woutput` and `boutput`. Assuming you are using the [`Optimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer) interface, and assuming that `loss` is the value you want to minimize, you can only *train* hidden and output layers by doing the following :

```
opt = GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss, var_list=[W3, b3, Woutput, boutput])
train_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
```

**NOTE**: `opt.minimize(loss, var_list)` does the equivalent of above, but I split it in two to illustrate the details.

`opt.compute_gradients` computes the gradients with respect to specific set of your model parameters, and you have full control as to what you consider as your model parameters. Note that you have to initialize Hidden layer 3 parameters from the older model, and Output layer parameters randomly. You can do so by restoring your new model from the original model which would copy all the parameters from the original model, and adding extra `tf.assign` operations to initialize the output layer parameters randomly.

Comment: Great! However, I still have two issues: (1) how do I get the list of variables in a layer if I created it using something like `fully_connected()`? I would love to be able to write something simple like `get_variables_in_scope("hidden3")`. (2) how do I replace the top layers? Also, I'm not sure this solution allows me to cache the output of the locked layers.

Comment: Hi - did you get anywhere with this idea? I'm looking to do something similar and have run into the same problem.